Doubt about terminology of regression models in directional statistics.
I am just starting in the world of directional statistics and a doubt has arisen regarding the terminology used to refer to regression models.
In principle, I think I understood that there can be three “families” of regression models depending on which is the dependent variable and which is the independent variable:

Independent variable (circular variable), dependent variable (linear variable).
Independent variable (linear variable), dependent variable (circular variable).
Independent variable (circularvariable), dependent variable (circular variable).

I have checked several bibliographic references, and in some occasions, I have seen that case 1 is called circular-linear regression and in other occasions it is called linear-circular regression. The same is true for case 2.
Examples from the literature are:
Topics in Circular Statistics. S. Rao Jammalamadaka A. SenGupta
Circular Data: An Overview with Discussion of One-Sample Tests.  Amanda Scott
Review on circular-linear regression models. Hanin Hazwani Mohammad et al
Which is the more correct terminology?
Thank you very much for your help
